# Linear electric currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-current

If I have a really long conductor (wire for example) as thin as possible, the currents inside are linear by aproximation? I have been thinking about Ampére's law $\int _c \vec B .d \vec {l} = I \mu$, where $c$ is a closed path. The linear current could be expressed as $I_l = \int \vec j . d \vec l$, where $ \vec j$ is a current density.

Is it possible to write just $ \vec B = \vec j \mu$ in this case?

I am somehow confused about the linear, surface and volume currents when they are the source for the magnetic field.

Comment: This is heavily dependent on how exactly your current is varying in time. DC currents tend to have more uniform current density in the wire than AC, which has a significant "skin effect" that concentrates current at the surface of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

The current relates to the current density by a surface integral $$I=\int_A \vec j d\vec a$$ where $A$ is the cross sectional surface of the wire. Thus you cannot equate the contour integral of Ampere's law to the surface integral relating the total current through the wire to the current density and the assumption $$ \vec B = \vec j \mu$$ is wrong.